# Finding the orthogonal projection

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

The angle between a line and a plane is thirty degrees. Segment $MN$ on the line has length $10$. What is the length of $MN's$ orthogonal projection on the plane?

I got 5 as an answer. Is that correct? I did the following:

$sin(30) = \frac{x}{10}$ which is 5.

Comment: You have written that $x/10$ is $5$. That's not what you meant --- you meant $x$ is $5$ --- but it is what you wrote. Also, you didn't say what you meant by $x$. From context, it's clear that $x$ is the side opposite the 30 degree angle --- but is that side the orthogonal projection? Isn't the side adjacent the orthogonal projection?

Comment: If the adjacent side is the orthogonal projection, then would my setup for the work of this problem be the following: $cos(30) = \frac{x}{10}$. Solve this equation for $x$.

Comment: Well, that's what I would get, too.

Answer (score 1):

If the incident angle is 30 degrees, the ratio between unit length on the incident line and unit length on the orthogonal projection (the shadow cast from a light perpendicular to the plane) is the cosine(30) (the ratio of the adjacent side of the triangle to the hypotenuse):

$$
\cos(30) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$
so, the length of the projection from a line of 10 units long is 
$$10\cos(30) = 5\sqrt{3}$$